# Primefaces Chart labels not showing in nested tabview

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I have a page with nested tabview , like this :

```
<p:tabView dynamic="true" id="tabView">
    <p:tab title="tab1">
        <p:tabView dynamic="true" >

            <p:tab title="subtab1" >
               // Some charts : LineChart , PieChart ...
               // Labels working
            </p:tab >

            <p:tab title="subtab2" >
               // Some charts : LineChart , PieChart ...
               // !! Labels not working !!
            </p:tab>

        </p:tabView>
    </p:tab>

    <p:tab title="tab2">
       // Some charts : LineChart , PieChart ...
       // Labels working
    </p:tab>
</p:tabView>
```

So the problem is that labels are not working in 'subtab2' , if i switch 'subtab2' and 'subtab1' labels work in 'subtab2' and not in 'subtab1'.

In 'tab1' and 'tab2' no problem !

I'm working with primefaces 5.1.

Comment: did you try PF 5.2? (emphasis on TRY, not directly use in production, just to check if it works there and we do not start chasing ghosts ;-)

Comment: No , I will try it and let you know

Comment: For khow what I did (in 5.1) is remove dynamic="true" from the nested tabView ... and it works.

Comment: Actually it work in PF 5.2 :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same code is working in PF 5.2 .

With PF 5.1 , to make it work, change the dynamic attribute to false in the second tabView.